# How to create auto-executing script for Chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console, shortcut-file

The idea is that when I open a certain site in Chrome using a desktop shortcut, I want a certain script to be automatically executed via the console. It is desirable that it starts executing when the page loads. This can be done? Through the properties of the shortcut or maybe a .bat file?
I want to make a shortcut for a quick reboot of the router, which, after opening the settings page, will log into the account and click on the necessary buttons to reboot. In manual mode, everything works, but I don’t know how to automate.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own chrome extension that does certain actions depending on what happens in the browser, it is actually quite easy to do and there are multiple guides out there on how to do it.

I will shamelessly plug my own guide on how to create one with react, be aware there are many other and probably better guides out there:

[Guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-a-chrome-extension-with-react-in-2020-5dadebf2135e)

Comment: I just remembered about tampermonkey. Maybe there is my solution.

Comment: Yeah same thing, pretty much. Never used it but looks like it does what you need.